# Create a Copy of a Google Sheet with just values not formulas

Tags: google-sheets

I have a simple script that copies a sheet but I'd like to improve it,

It copies the sheet but I'd like it to set the vlues that are currently formulas as fixed values so I can have a record of how the sheet looked each week.

I'd also like to rename the sheet as "sales" and todays date if possible?

Here is what I'm currently using

```
function Duplicate() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    ss.getSheetByName('To order test').copyTo(ss)      
}
```

Thanks if anyone can help

Big T

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script code:

```
function Duplicate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('To order test').copyTo(ss);
  var r = s.getDataRange();
  r.setValues(r.getValues());
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),'yyyy-MM-dd');
  s.setName(date);
};
```

Comment: Thank You Kishan, This works exactly as I need it to :-)